# TChromium how to add "Save Picture" item in Context Menu?

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I have TChromium Browser, but when Im visiting web sites, and trying to save pictures, like in Google Chrome, i can't see "Save Picture" item :(

How to add this item ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is [`no such build-in command`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/cef_menu_id_t.html) for saving images, but you can make a custom menu item with your own command like shows [`this code`](http://pastebin.com/fq8QmzCU).

Comment: The only way to add that missing *Save image as...* command is to do it in the `OnBeforeContextMenu` and handle the command execution in the `OnContextMenuCommand` is also a must. So, there's not much to try, only much to improve ;-)

Comment: I have my own ContextMenu, instead of default. I did it like this : model.Clear;
ChromiumPopup.Popup(Mouse.CursorPos.X,Mouse.CursorPos.Y);  And i recovered missing "Copy Link" item, now will recover "Save image" item :) Will try your code :)

Comment: You don't need to use your own popup menu. If you need just a pure popup menu (without custom images or something), the built-in one with the component events gives you everything you need. You can add & remove certain commands (without cleaning the whole menu by using `model.Clear`) and of course run whichever command actions you want.

Comment: If i trying to build my own PopUp menu, whit pictures and other things, i cant close it, because i cant catch TChromiumOnClick event, for closing my ownmade PopUp menu on this event. So at this time, realy i'm using default PopUp menu.

Comment: [TLama](http://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama), please, update code for new version Chromium for delphi xe2
[this code](http://pastebin.com/fq8QmzCU)